# title on toolbar not showing up

Tags: xml, kotlin

I created a toolbar that has a title on it but the tile isn't showing. The colors don't clash so I don't know what is the issue. This is my xml code where I have my title and style xml to hold the design.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:title="@string/ucc_it_online"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/ToolBar"/>
```

this is my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@color/yellow</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
      <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
      <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarWithTitle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
      <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
      <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AdmiTextViewStyle">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fenix</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also as you can see there are two toolbars,one shows the title but for come reason I am unable to change the text size. Have been having this issue for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using app:title -

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    app:title="@string/ucc_it_online"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/ToolBar"/>
```

If you look at the design view of your layout & search the attributes list for "title", the only one that comes up is app:title - even though in the Android developer documentation for Toolbar, the android:title attribute is listed (maybe because you're using appcompat toolbar?).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar#attr_android:title